# Amazon SES/Hotmail issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, hotmail

Trying to send emails through Amazon SES as part of webform submission through gateway API. I have a verified email address which is my own. I have tried test emails and also through the lambda function which succeeds. But no email received. The SES console is telling me it has had no bounces. Am I missing any configuration information? is there something I'm missing or need to know? I have sent a support request to Microsoft to check on there end as well.

[image: amazon see metrics]

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Thanks chris yeah i have